# How to send final game score between Cocos Creator scenes?

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm trying to create a game with Cocos Creator. I'm using more than one file in the game. Like `Game.js` `GameOver.js` `Jump.js` etc. I'm collecting scores with `GainScore.js`. I have to send final score to `GameOver.js` file. I show the score properly during the game. But when the game is over I have to send it to the other screen. How can I use the game score as global?

My gainScore function:

```
  gainScore() {
    this.score += 1;
    if (this.scoreDisplay === null) return;
    this.scoreDisplay.string = this.score;
  },
```

My `GameOver.js` file

```
cc.Class({
    extends: cc.Component,

    properties: {
        scoreEnd: {
            default: null,
            type: cc.Label,
        },
    },

    start() {
        this.scoreEnd.string = this.score.toString(); // I can't access with this way
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CommonJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html). Create a new file called `Global.js`.

```
scripts
  |__ GameOver.js
  |__ GainScore.js
  |__ Global.js
```

and keep your global variables here.

Global.js:

```
module.exports = {
    score: 0
};
```

And use with require in other files:

```
let Globals = require("Globals");

....

gainScore() {
   Globals.score += 1; // not this.score, should be Globals.score
   if (this.scoreDisplay === null) return;
   this.scoreDisplay.string = Globals.score;
},
```

You should require all other files that will use

```
let Globals = require("Globals");

cc.Class({
    extends: cc.Component,

    properties: {
        scoreEnd: {
            default: null,
            type: cc.Label,
        },
    },

    start() {
        this.scoreEnd.string = Globals.score.toString();
    },
});
```